# if one site blocks the entrance with tor browser, what can I do?

Tags: blocked-services

I want to visit to a site anonymously, but I can not login with Tor.
How to make sure that this site did not know that I use Tor?
They are forbidden clones, but I need them.

Comment: Tor exit relays are published information, aside from a small fraction of some relays some of the time providing false negatives. If a site wants to block Tor, it can block Tor. You should ask the site operators to allow Tor users and encourage them to allow anonymous use through, perhaps an alternative means to prevent abuse.

Comment: this is not possible. as stated, the tor exits are public domain. your best bet would be to configure TOR > SSH server as a SOCKS5 proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hide this from websites. Unless the website operators unblock Tor, there is nothing you can do.

You said right in your question "they are forbidden clones," which means you are using Tor to do something you shouldn't be doing anyway.